# In google app script editor, the autocomplete feature works with semi column instead of the point

Tags: google-apps-script, autocomplete, google-apps-script-editor

I'm Guillaume a french beginner in google app script editor.
I have a problem with autocomplete feature. It would works with the dot (.) and in my case, autocomplete works with semi column (;) or crtl+space but it's not easy to use.
It mean that autocomplete displays something when I "close" a command or a line.
How can I change that please ?

I tried to change the language of the editor in English but it's the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758602) with AZERTY keyboards. A work-around would be changing your keyboard layout to english, like US. You can click on the star next to the issue number (at top) to subscribe and give more priority to the report.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer but it's not convenient to change the keyboard. As you advise me, I clicked on the star and will wait for another answer. I'm surprised that I'm the only one to have this problem.